# uitextfield in static uitableview do not get updated in container view

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitextfield, uitableview

I have a static UITableViewController embedded in UIViewController in iOS 5. The static table view has UITextField.

The static UITableViewController when independently used updated the UITextfield correctly with changing values. The keyboard resigns etc.,

But when embedded the UITextfield are not getting updated with the changes. The keyboard comes up but does not resign...

How to updated the UITextfields in embedded tableview?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake - When you drag and drop table view from one table view controller to another the outlets still point to old controller, they had to be deleted and new outlets created in the storyboard